# Multiple select option into a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, html-select, store

I have a selectbox list. Is it possible to select multiple options?

```
<select name="access_list[ ]" size="7" multiple="multiple">
    <?php $res=mysql_query("select * from list" ,$conn);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    echo"<option value=".$row['id'].">".$row['name']."</option>";?>
</select>
```

How are the values ​that will be selected (select multiple values ​together) stored in the array?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use name as `name="access_list[]"` without space.

And you can get selected options with `$_POST['access_list']`

`$_POST['access_list']` is `array` that contains selected options

Answer (score 6):

Replace your select tag with this:

```
<select name="access_list[]" size="7" multiple="multiple">
```

If you want to get the array, you can do it like this:

```
$data = $_POST['access_list'];
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 2):

store as array then in your php is like this.

```
<?php

    $access_list = $_POST['access_list'];

    foreach($access_list as $value)
    {
        //Do your code Here
    }


?>
```