# Having trouble pulling items from arrays into a list

Tags: php

I am trying to create a web page that will populate a shopkeepers inventory. I have placed the items the shop will be selling inside of the array, but I cannot get the php to output multiple items from the array

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <form method="post" action="spell-shop.php">
        tier 1 spells in shop<input type="text" name="tier1"><br>
        tier 2 spells in shop<input type="text" name="tier2"><br>
        tier 3 spells in shop<input type="text" name="tier3"><br>
        Master spells in shop<input type="text" name="master"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
<?php
    $spells1 = array(
        'Commune - level 1 - Any' , 'Detect Magic - Level 1 - Any' , 'Devine Favor - Level 1 - Any' , 'Magic Missile - Level 1 - Any' , 'Prestidigation - Level 1 - Any' , 'True Strike - Level 1 - Any' , 'Shield - Level 2 - Any' , 'Locate Object - Level 2 - Any' , 'Prayer of Healing - level 2 - Any' , 'Alarm - Level 1 - Air' , 'Feather Fall - Level 1 - Air' , 'Jump - Level 1 - Air' , 'Longstrider - Level 1 - Air' , 'Shocking Grasp - Level 1 - Air' , 'Tensers Floating Disk - Level 2 - Air' , 'Thunderous Smite Lelvel 2 - Air' , 'Find Traps Level 2 - Air' , 'Gust of Wind Level - 2 - Air' , 'Knock - Level 2 - Air' , 'Levitate - Level 2 - Air' , 'Rope - Trick 2 - Air'
    );
    if (isset($_POST['tier1'])) {
        $name = $_POST['tier1'];
        $inventory = array_rand($spells1, $name);
        echo "$inventory";
    }
?>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You're only using one POST array here and you need to treat the input(s) as an array also.

Comment: `array_rand` takes two parameters. THe first is the array, while the second is the number entries to be chosen in that array.

Comment: check this post : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957588/store-multiple-select-option-into-a-php-array`

Answer (score -1):

You can't echo out an array like that. For array_rand, you supply an array to pick from, then the second parameter is the number of items you wish to pull out randomly.

Example `$inventory = array_rand($spells1,2)`;

Will put 2 elements from $spells1 into $inventory

So now you'd need to loop through $inventory and echo out its results.

```
foreach($inventory as $item){
   echo $item;
}
```

For what you want you'd need $name / $_POST['tier1'] to be numeric;

Comment: Man...that research in hindsight is really a killer, isn't it? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯