# WordPress Settings field: Saving multiple <select> options

Tags: php, wordpress

In a WordPress Options Page I have a settings field that has an HTML `select` with the attribute of `multiple`. The `select`'s `options` are dynamically populated by Custom Post Types, all is fine there. I can save one value into an array, but not more. This is the current `var_dump`:

```
array(1) { ["awc_cpt"]=> string(12) "board_member" }
```

Ideally I'd like the array to return:

```
array(
    "board_member" => "board_member",
    "another_cpt" => "another_cpt",
    // and so on for as many Custom Post Types as needed
)
```

I am a beginner at PHP, so I may be missing some fundamentals.

**Question: How do I save multiple selected `options` into the array for this WordPress setting?**

```
<?php

class AWC_Redirect {
    private $awc_redirect_options;
    public $non_archived_posts = array();

    public function __construct() {
        if( is_admin() ){
            add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'awc_redirect_add_plugin_page' ) );
            add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'awc_redirect_page_init' ) );
        }

        add_action( 'template_redirect', array( $this, 'AWC_template_redirect') );
    }

    public function awc_redirect_add_plugin_page() {
        add_options_page(
            'AWC Redirect', // page_title
            'AWC Redirect', // menu_title
            'manage_options', // capability
            'awc-redirect', // menu_slug
            array( $this, 'awc_redirect_create_admin_page' ) // function
        );
    }

    public function awc_redirect_create_admin_page() {
        $this->awc_redirect_options = get_option( 'awc_redirect_option_name' ); ?>

        <div class="wrap">
            <h2>AWC Redirect</h2>
            <p></p>
            <?php settings_errors(); ?>

            <form method="post" action="options.php">
                <?php
                    settings_fields( 'awc_redirect_option_group' );
                    do_settings_sections( 'awc-redirect-admin' );
                    submit_button();
                ?>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php var_dump(get_option( 'awc_redirect_option_name' )); ?>
    <?php }

    public function awc_redirect_page_init() {
        register_setting(
            'awc_redirect_option_group', // option_group
            'awc_redirect_option_name', // option_name
            array( $this, 'awc_redirect_sanitize' ) // sanitize_callback
        );

        add_settings_section(
            'awc_redirect_setting_section', // id
            'Settings', // title
            array( $this, 'awc_redirect_section_info' ), // callback
            'awc-redirect-admin' // page
        );

        add_settings_field(
            'awc_cpt', // id
            'Custom Post Types', // title
            array( $this, 'awc_cpt_callback' ), // callback
            'awc-redirect-admin', // page
            'awc_redirect_setting_section' // section
        );
    }

    public function awc_redirect_sanitize($input) {
        $sanitary_values = array();
        if ( isset( $input['awc_cpt'] ) ) {
            $sanitary_values['awc_cpt'] = $input['awc_cpt'];
        }

        return $sanitary_values;
    }

    public function awc_redirect_section_info() {

    }

    public function awc_cpt_callback() { 
        ?> <select name="awc_redirect_option_name[awc_cpt]" id="awc_cpt" multiple>
            <?php echo $this->AWC_get_post_types(); ?>
        </select> <?php
    }

    // get all post types that are archived => true
    public function AWC_get_post_types(){

        $post_types = $this->AWC_list_post_types();
        $op = '';

        foreach ( $post_types  as $post_type ) {
            $op .= $this->AWC_get_post_details( $post_type );
        }
        return $op;
    }

    public function AWC_list_post_types(){
        $args = array(
            'public'   => true,
            '_builtin' => false
        );

        $output = 'names'; // names or objects, note names is the default
        $operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
        $op = '';

        $post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator );
        return $post_types;
    }

    // loop through and spit out into <select>. If they are set, mark as selected.
    public function AWC_get_post_details( $post_type ){
        $op = get_post_type_object( $post_type );
        if( !$post_type || false === $op->has_archive ){
            return;
        }

        $name = $op->name;
        $label = $op->label;
        $archive_link = get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type );

        // Had to do the following because array_push doesn't work on an empty variable... 
        // ...so set it with the first, push with the rest.
        if( empty( $this->non_archived_posts ) ){
            $this->non_archived_posts[] = $name;
        } else{
            array_push( $this->non_archived_posts, $name );
        }

        $selected = (isset( $this->awc_redirect_options['awc_cpt'] ) && $this->awc_redirect_options['awc_cpt'] === $name ) ? 'selected' : '';

        $select_options = '
                <option value="' . $name . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $label . '</option>
        ';

        return $select_options;
    }

    public function AWC_template_redirect(){
        $post_types = $this->AWC_list_post_types();
        foreach( $post_types as $cpt ){
            if ( is_singular( $cpt ) && get_post_type_object( $cpt )->has_archive ) {
                $redirectLink = get_post_type_archive_link( $cpt );
                wp_redirect( $redirectLink, 302 );
                exit;
            }
        }
    }

}

$awc_redirect = new AWC_Redirect();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [store multiple select option into a PHP array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957588/store-multiple-select-option-into-a-php-array)

Comment: Where are you saving the setting in the above code?

Comment: @Steve do you mean where in the DB?

Comment: No, which line of code in your question saves the field

Comment: `submit_button()` is where it happens I believe. It then gets saved to `wp_options` in the DB.

Comment: Sorry, i was confusing the settings api with the options api. Your problem is almost certainly down to the name of your form field. Multiple select fields should have a name with array notation `name="awc_redirect_option_name[awc_cpt][]"`

Comment: that's really close! (and I **swore** I tried that!) it's an indexed array now, I'm aiming for associative

Comment: @Steve I added a counter and got it working, if you want to add yours as an answer please do. I'll add mine as an answer in the meantime.

Comment: Glad i could help you. I wont write an answer because im not particularly familiar with this api. @ reply me when you post your answer though, so i can take a look.