# PHP post with dynamic entries created in JS

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a button that allows the user to add another row to add different types of returned equipment. I am posting this data to another page to print out. If I try and retrieve the data from the post array, I can only get the last in the entry

I've tried setting the name to name="device[]" then adding a value of "key" but since I'm using a drop down select, I can't do that.

```
<select name="device-type[]">
   <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Equipment Type</option>
   <option value="dvr">DVR</option>
   <option value="modem">Modem</option>
   <option value="router">Router</option>
   <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

I have a button that calls a JS function to just add another select element identical to that.

JS code:

```
function addBox(){
    $("#devices").append('<select name="device-type" class="focus:outline-none plain-field">\n' +
        '                    <option>Select Equipment Type</option>\n' +
        '                    <option value="dvr">DVR</option>\n' +
        '                    <option value="modem">Modem</option>\n' +
        '                    <option value="router">Router</option>\n' +
        '                    <option value="other">Other</option>\n' +
        '                </select>\n' +
        '                <input class="focus:outline-none plain-field" name="device-number" type="text" placeholder="CMAC/SN">\n' +
        '                <input type="checkbox" name="power-cord" class="">Power Cord?\n' +
        '                <input type="checkbox" name="remote" class="">Remote?\n' +
        '                <br>');
    return false;
```

PHP to retrieve the information from that:

```
<p><?php echo $_POST['device-type']?></p>
<p><?php echo $_POST['device-number']?></p>
```

My question is, how can I retrieve the device type and number in the post array?

Comment: Can we please see examples of your JS and PHP to see exactly how you are trying to get the select tag built from that info? Thank you.

Comment: @woodrow I added some of my code to explain what I have so far

Answer (score 0):

Simply make your HTML `select` tag accept multiple values. E.g:

```
<select name="device_type[]" class="focus:outline-none plain-field" multiple>
....
</select>
```

You can get the selected values on the PHP end using `$_POST['device_type']`

Refer to [store multiple select option into a PHP array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957588/store-multiple-select-option-into-a-php-array) for more information

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add `[]` brackets to your field names to make them a multi array for `$_POST` to handle processing. Also, if you want to identify each row by an `index`, on clicking the `ADD` button, you can count the amount of `select` boxes generated to create a count and use that as the key index for each `array`. If you run the following below in a `PHP` file, click the `ADD` button to add some `select` boxes, and then click `SUBMIT`, you will see your data echo'd out as a `multi-dimensional array`. I also gave your initial select box an index of 0 for the multi array.

[image]
[image]

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST);
        foreach($_POST['device-type'] as $key => $type) {
            echo "<b>Type:</b> " . $type . " ";
            echo (isset($_POST['device-number']) && isset($_POST['device-number'][$key]) && !empty($_POST['device-number'][$key])) ? "<b>Number:</b> " .$_POST['device-number'][$key] . " " : "";
            echo (isset($_POST['power-cord']) && isset($_POST['power-cord'][$key]) && !empty($_POST['power-cord'][$key])) ? "<b>Power Cord:</b> " .$_POST['power-cord'][$key] . " " : "";
            echo (isset($_POST['remote']) && isset($_POST['remote'][$key]) && !empty($_POST['remote'][$key])) ? "<b>Remote:</b> " .$_POST['remote'][$key] . " " : "";
            echo "<br/>";
        }
        echo "</pre>";
    }
    ?>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addBox() {
            //console.log($('select.plain-field').length + 1);
            var rowCount = $('select.plain-field').length + 1;
            $("#devices").append('<br/><select name="device-type[' + rowCount + ']" class="focus:outline-none plain-field">\n' +
                                 '                    <option value="">Select Equipment Type</option>\n' +
                                 '                    <option value="dvr">DVR</option>\n' +
                                 '                    <option value="modem">Modem</option>\n' +
                                 '                    <option value="router">Router</option>\n' +
                                 '                    <option value="other">Other</option>\n' +
                                 '                </select>\n' +
                                 '                <input class="focus:outline-none plain-field" name="device-number[' + rowCount + ']" type="text" placeholder="CMAC/SN">\n' +
                                 '                <input type="checkbox" name="power-cord[' + rowCount + ']" class="">Power Cord?\n' +
                                 '                <input type="checkbox" name="remote[' + rowCount + ']" class="">Remote?\n' +
                                 '                ');
            return false;
        }
    </script>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div id="devices">
            <select name="device-type[0]">
                <option value="">Select Equipment Type</option>
                <option value="dvr">DVR</option>
                <option value="modem">Modem</option>
                <option value="router">Router</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <input type="button" onclick="addBox();" value="Add [+]" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Did this help? Please let me know if you have any questions.